# Python: Set operation messing up on Wordnet Lemmas

Tags: python, wordnet

I'm doing a set operation on a set of wordnet lemmas.

The operation, however, eliminates items in the list by doing a faulty comparison

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('angry')[0].lemmas()[0].derivationally_related_forms()
[Lemma('wrath.n.02.anger'), Lemma('anger.n.01.anger'), Lemma('anger.n.02.anger'),\
Lemma('anger.n.02.angriness')]
>>> set(wn.synsets('angry')[0].lemmas()[0].derivationally_related_forms())
set([Lemma('wrath.n.02.anger'), Lemma('anger.n.02.angriness')])
```

As you can see, lemma 'anger.n.01.anger' and 'anger.n.02.anger' are eliminated.

How can I deal with this? I could convert them to strings, but I need to operate on them as wordnet objects later.

I'm using python 2.7, by the way.

Comment: The first three wordnet objects are internally equivalent although not the same `w[0]==w[1]==w[2] ->
True` and `hash(w[0])==hash(w[2])==hash(w[2]) -> True`. I don't see why you need to call set on the result. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm recursively calling hyponyms and hypernyms, which will give me duplicates. I have no idea why they would be internally equivalent, considering they map to different lemmas and different synsets. That's really dumb.

Comment: @NikhilPrabhu: `Lemma` objects represent the word form, which in this case, the first three have the same word form: "anger". This word form "anger" is present in multiple (3 in this case) synsets, and WordNet creates a separate `Lemma` object to hold different relations of the lemma `anger` with the synset it is in, but they are all still the same lemma "anger". The fourth one has the form "angriness", that's why it is different.